# facebook php sdk get pages-id without asking for manage_pages permission

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook login on my website.
When a user logs in using a fb page fan account, user graph api gives me

https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100002628426645

instead of https://www.facebook.com/captainbloodlegacy (the real page url)

I really need to get this real fan page url instead that profile.php?id=xxx

I know it is possible by asking for manage_pages permission but Facebook wants developpers to submit their app for review when we use extended permissions such as manage_pages and I don't want to ask them for a review.

I don't want to write, or to delete pages, I just want to read the real url of the pages associated with the fan page fb account...

I'm using fb php sdk 3.2.3...

An idea?

Thanks a lot

Eviral

Comment: You can try querying for the "username" of the page.This is the alias of the Page. For example, for www.facebook.com/platform the username is 'platform'. This doc covers what you can and cannot get based on the access token permissions you have. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't know the username (alias) of the page.
I'm only getting https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100002628426645 from Facebook connect and not https://www.facebook.com/plateform.
I need to get page username (alias) or page id but i can't...